# Does a HDMI output male to two input female connector exist?

Tags: hdmi, connector

I only have one HDMI slot in my tv but two HDMI input devices, I was wondering if a connector like this existed to save me having to take out and plugin the other device whenever i want to use it.

I googled it and found only a input male to two output female HDMI splitter. So does the connector I described in the title exist?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an [HDMI Switch](http://hometheater.about.com/od/audioandvideoaccessories/tp/hdmiswitchers.htm).  It will take multiple HDMI inputs to a single input and switch between them.   You can find them at any store that sells any electronics.